# Remove item from list jquery li

Tags: jquery

Here's a simple HTML "todo app" that I have a text input that will display that text on the page.  Each time you enter text and click the button a new "todo" will appear.  I want to be able to delete a todo and have it disappear by clicking on the text.

I have it working where it will remove the entire  but can't seem to get it to allow individual li to be deleted after they are created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script>

function myTask()
$('#btnName').click(function(){
    var text = $('#inputName').val();
    if(text.length){
        $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.taskList')
    }
});

</script>

</head>

<body onload="myTask()">


<div id="container">My Todos</div>
<input type="test" id="inputName" />
<button id="btnName">Click me!</button>

<ul class="taskList"></ul>
<script>
    $("ul").click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Target the actual `li`

```
$(".tasklist").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: @tuneyfish -- No problem, be sure to mark the answer when you can.